# Unable to load a fontawesome using laravel/mix - webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass, laravel-7

I am trying to load font awesome using npm package manager and webpack in laravel project.

I tried many solution with/without $fa-font-path but none of them are working.

I tried:

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/";
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
```

```
 @import "~@fortawesome";
```

with/without ~ sign too.

Each time font files are generated on the public/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/

It seems like it is considering default font path: `$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";`

And the other issue is that it always look for `/css/~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff` this path. I dont know why it is adding `~` in css. I belive its `$fa-font-path` set inside fontawesome _variable library. While the generated directory is `@fortawesome` without ~

So I need to fix two issues here:
1) Fix the path in laravel mix webpack
2) Remove prefix ~ sign from path and make $fa-font-path work

Answer (score 0):

In `/resources/sass/app.scss` add...

```
// Fontawesome
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

You don't need: `$fa-font-path`. The `~` references the `/node_modules` directory.